# Linq to SQL how to override method

Tags: linq-to-sql

I created Linq to SQL classes and override ToString method, but when I get object of class and call ToString method it returns full type of object as string. So, maybe Linq to SQL overrides this method in aother place? And how can I use method, overrided by myself? (I need exacly ToString method, not any other)

Comment: How did you override it?  Show your code.  Does the auto-generated code also have an override?  Did you override it in the generated code or in a separate partial class?

Comment: I override in auto-generated code.
http://pastebin.com/m0d8iFMZ
1098 line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're modifying generated files, which means re-generating the files will remove your modifications.

Don't modify the generated files.  Note that the generated objects are `partial` classes, so you can modify them by creating separate files with `partial` classes of the same name.  Something like this:

```
namespace MCN.Web
{
    public partial class Mod
    {
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name;
        }
    }
}
```

Since it's a separate file, it won't be overwritten when generating the code.